# How to use search:search API to search in txt file?

Tags: xquery, marklogic

How to search within a text file(.txt) with search:search API in Marklogic. I want to upload a txt file to Marklogic and use search:search API to search its contents. How can I do it ?

Answer (score 2):

search:search() should be able to find hits in text documents.

```
xdmp:document-insert("/text.txt", text { "Hello World " } )
```

Then

```
search:search("Hello")
```

Should return a hit.  (Yes, text documents are represented as documents with an XML text node at the root).

Comment: I have tried this but search:search is not returning any results for txt file.

Comment: Perhaps the file is marked as binary for some reason.  Binary files won't be searched.  Try xdmp:uri-content-type to check.